# Executing the perl script in dos with perl invoked makes difference?

Tags: perl, perl-module, win32ole, ansi-colors

why is the behaviour so ?

`test2color.pl` contains:

```
#! perl -slw
use strict;
use Win32::Console::ANSI;
use Term::ANSIColor qw(:constants);

print BLACK, ON_WHITE, "black on white\n";
print WHITE, ON_BLACK, "white on black\n";
print GREEN, ON_CYAN, BLINK, "garish!\n";
print RESET;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Did you install the `Win32::Console::ANSI` module ?

Answer (score 6):

Your

```
H:\test\perl>perl test2color.pl
```

uses the first perl(.exe) it finds in the PATH environment variable. This may be the perl from your cygwin installation.

```
H:\test\perl>test2color.pl
```

uses OS information to associate the extension .pl to a specific commandline/executable that will run all your .pl. `ftype` and `assoc` can be used to show/manipulate these associations.

I assume that your ftype for .pl points to - the completely different - `c:\Perl\bin\perl.exe`.

Comment: `use if $^O eq 'MSWin32', 'Win32::Console::ANSI';` will make it work under cygwin as well as your Windows build of Perl.

Comment: Yes I have Strawberry Perl installed and the Cygwin (with Less perl module I guess). and in the PATH, the CYGWIN path comes first before strawberry. So Since the Strawberry is by default supports ANSI & WIN32. and the Strawberry instalation might have done this job of file association

SO if I need to make my script more portable, (running on the system where strawberry/Active perl is not installed, with the addition of packages)

if( ($^O eq 'MSWin32') && ($^O eq 'Term'))
{
  print BLACK, ON_WHITE, "black on white\n";
}
else
{
  Print "NO Color Sorry";
}

this should work I believe